# Lines around header (First site ever)

Tags: html, css

Soo, good time of day to everyone,

Very recently I started studying HTML and CSS and decided to make a site of my own design, all was good until I bumped into this bug... In desktop view there's a line at the top and in mobile there are lines under bottom and around right side.

I've tried to solve this problem following various methods and tips described in the internet, but miserably failed.

[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VwR4.png)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ry42ud4o/1/)

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SpiderWorld| Биология</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Menu.css">
</head>

<body class="Biology">
<div class="Wrapper">
    <div>
        <header class="BiologyHead">
        <img src="Icons/Logo1.png" style="max-width: 6%; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
            <label class="mail">Email</label>
            <label class="pass">Password</label>
            <input class="Password">
            <input class="Email">
        <button class="Submit">Submit</button>
            <nav role="navigation">
              <div id="menuToggle">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span></span>
                <span class="Bio"></span>
                <span class="Bio"></span>
                <span class="Bio"></span>
                <ul id="menu">
                  <a href="#"><li>Главная</li></a>
                  <a href="#"><li>Биология</li></a>
                  <a href="#"><li>Виды</li></a>
                  <a href="#"><li>Потенциал</li></a>
                  <a href="#"><li>Галерея</li></a>
                  <a href="#"><li>Регистрация</li></a>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>  
        </header>
    </div>

    <div class="Content" id="particles-js">
    <script src="Scripts/particles.js"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/js/app.js"></script>
        <section class="Content1">
            <img class="EducationInside" src="Icons/BiologyInside1.png">
            <p><img class="EducationFace" src="Icons/BiologyOutside1.png">Прежде всего паук не насекомое, а паук. У насекомых есть голова, у паука голова и грудь слиты воедино. Цефалотораксом называют это головогрудное объединение. На голове у насекомых усики, а у раков, если заметили, даже две пары усов – большие и маленькие. У паука – никаких усов! Так, по усам ориентируясь, распознать можно в типе членистоногих представителей трех подтипов: насекомых, раков и пауков (с паукообразными в придачу). Усы паукообразных и других хелицеровых: скорпионов, сольпуг, клещей и прочих – переделаны эволюцией в хелицеры. Это то, чем паук кусается, – острые, в суставе сгибающиеся (чтобы укусить!) и пронзенные тонким каналом, на манер змеиных зубов, хитиновые крючья. По каналу стекает яд – прямо в рану, сделанную хелицерами.</p>
            <p><img class="EducationLegs" src="Icons/BiologyOutside2.png">Но не только, разумеется, в усах дело; насекомые, например, бегают на шести ногах, а пауки – на восьми. Насекомые смотрят на мир выпукло – двумя большими, как говорят, фасеточными глазами, составленными из многих мелких глазков. У пауков глаза простые – не мозаика фасеток.</p>
            <p><img class="EducationEyes" src="Icons/BiologyOutside3.png"> Но зато глаз у них, как ног, восемь. Все сидят на объединенной с грудью голове, обычно парами. Два средних крупнее других и без зеркальца внутри – не блестят. Лишь у немногих пауков не восемь, а шесть глаз, у иных – даже четыре, два, а то и вовсе нет глаз. Но это исключение, которое, как известно, только подтверждает правило.</p>
        </section>
        <!-- scripts -->
    </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="BiologyFoot">
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";

.Wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.Push {
    height: 1000px;
}

.MainFoot,.BiologyFoot {
    height: 200px;
}

.parallax {
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.first {
    background-image: url(../Images/Fon2.jpg);
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body
{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* make it look decent enough */
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #cdcdcd;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", "Avenir", sans-serif;

  overflow-x: hidden; /* needed because hiding the menu on the right side is not perfect,  */
}

body.Main {
    background-image: url(../Images/FonMain2.jpg);
}

body.Biology {
    background-image: url(../Images/FonMain4.jpg);
}

header {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.0));
}

.BiologyHead {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(40,40,40,1.00), rgba(20,20,20,1.00));
    position: fixed; left: 50px; right: 50px; top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.MainFoot {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00),rgba(9, 35, 3, 1.00));
}

.BiologyFoot {
    border-style: none;
    position: fixed; left: 50px; right: 50px; bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to top,rgba(40,40,40,1.00), rgba(20,20,20,1.00));
    z-index: -1;
}

h1 {
    display: block;
    max-width: 15%;
}

.Text1{
    display: block;
    color: rgba(57,55,236,1.00);
    max-width: 10%;
    position: absolute; top: 1px; right: 10px;
    padding-right: 85px;
}

.Content {
    background: rgba(39,39,39,1.00);
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 100; right: 50px;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.Content1 {
    position: absolute; left: 70px; right: 70px; top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0.0), rgba(255,255,255,0.50), rgba(255,255,255,0.50), rgba(255,255,255,0.50), rgba(255,255,255,0.00));
    background-size: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", "serif";
}

img.EducationInside {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-width: 95%;
}

p {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

img.EducationFace {
    float:right;
    margin: 10px;
    max-width: 30%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

img.EducationLegs {
    float:left;
    margin: 10px;
    max-width: 30%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

img.EducationEyes {
    float:right;
    margin: 10px;
    max-width: 20%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

img.Decoration {
    max-width: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    opacity:0;
    animation:load_up 2s forwards;
    -webkit-animation:load_up 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes load_up{
    from{opacity:0;bottom:100%}
    to{opacity:1;bottom:20%;}

}
@-webkit-keyframes load_up{
    from{opacity:0;bottom:100%}
    to{opacity:1;bottom:20%;}

}



a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(156,233,210,1.00);

  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

a:hover
{
  color: rgba(96,229,132,1.00);
}

#menuToggle
{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;

  z-index: 1;

  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;

  cursor: pointer;

  opacity: 0; /* hide this */
  z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */

  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

/*
 * Just a quick hamburger
 */
#menuToggle span.Bio
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;

  background: rgba(54,71,124,1.00);
  border-radius: 3px;

  z-index: 1;

  transform-origin: 4px 0px;

  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span.Home
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;

  background: rgba(154,112,80,1.00);
  border-radius: 3px;

  z-index: 1;

  transform-origin: 4px 0px;

  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

/* 
 * Transform all the slices of hamburger
 * into a crossmark.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}

/*
 * But let's hide the middle one.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

/*
 * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

/*
 * Make this absolute positioned
 * at the top left of the screen
 */
#menu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: -150px;
  right: -100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;


  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.00), rgba(0,0,0,0.55), rgba(0,0,0,0.00));
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */

  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);

  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

#menu li
{
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

/*
 * And let's fade it in from the left
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
  opacity: 1;
}

canvas{
  display:block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}


/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(20,20,20,1.00);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

/* Login */

.Email {
    width: 90px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-style: none;
    position: absolute; top: 17.5px; right: 285px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.mail {
    position: absolute; top: 19px; right: 379px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
}

.Password {
    width: 90px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-style: none;
    position: absolute; top: 17.5px; right: 120px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.pass {
    position: absolute; top: 19px; right: 215px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
}

.Submit {
    width: 50px;
    height: 17px;
    position: absolute; top: 17.5px; right: 60px;
    background: rgba(54,71,124,1.00);
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-style: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    section {
        font-size: 70%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    section {
        font-size: 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create like a https://jsfiddle.net/ or something so we can see the issue for ourselves? Troubleshooting images isn't exactly the best way to do it.

Comment: Okay, wait a little longer.

Comment: With my 1.5K lines js I couldn't include it in the snippet. And 'cause I'm here for the first day I coudn't figure how to include images in the snippet, Sorry.

Comment: @DarkNess Change images with something from the web

Comment: Images are here, but the js still lacking, it's 55k characters, the body doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *the lines* that you want you remove are the borders you can solve this by adding to `Wrapper`

```
.Wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-width: 0;
}
```

Also remove the div that is inside the `Wrapper` `div` ,is useless

Edit:
**The solution** 
add

```
body{
  background-color:black;
}
```

to your css,you had white background ,that was the problem ( and also some padding, but this will solve the problem)

Comment: Also, when I try to reposition header by changing position's atribute to something else instead of fixed and changing header's top, left and right atributes, lines are gone, well at least in mobile view. Problem is for the end design header must be fixed:(

Comment: @DarkNess Change border and its width to 0 like I did to Wrapper but you do that for the header.On snippet I don't see any lines

Comment: I added this to wrapper and it didn't work:( Fiddle is here.

Comment: @DarkNess You add to both items and removed the div ? Then should be from navbar,if I had your code I would change it myself

Comment: Then can send me your email? I'll send you a folder with all the files.

Comment: @DarkNess Just do the edits that I told you and come back with feedback

Comment: Well, with border: 0...both in header and wrapper and without that div....it didn't work. What can I do about the nav?

Comment: @DarkNess add 0 border to it too .I checked your fiddle ,it didn't match the photo ,in photo you have elements that aren't in the code,also in the code aren't any "lines"

Comment: I saw this too, but in the chrome and in the dev console in chrome they are present.

Comment: And I doubt it's something wrong with chrome. As I wrote, I can send a folder with all the files so you or anyone else can open html file in chrome or another browser and see for yourself that they are there.

Comment: @DarkNess Just upload photos on some website and use them in a fiddle so I can see the lines there and change them

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/AetKw http://melkorthegreat.imgur.com/all/?third_party=1

Comment: @DarkNess upload the photos of the project,man, and use them in a fiddle to be get exactly your website so I can check it there

Comment: Oh, now I've got it, sorry.

Comment: Fiddle's updated with my images. There are no lines in the fiddle, but there are when I open html file in chrome.

Comment: I don't get it, it's two options: 1) Fiddle's working better than chrome or 2) I've done something somewhere entirely wrong...

Comment: Opened html in internet explorer...well it turns out to be the chrome's issue after all, 'cause there are no "lines" in IE. Thanks for help:)

Comment: Maybe you refreshed the website so many times that chrome saved it and you can't see the updated version only if you disable cache in dev tools. Try that and tell me if the problem was solved

Comment: Disabling cache did nothing, so now I'm convinced that it's 1) Chrome's bug or 2) I need to add support of something for Chrome in my CSS or somewhere else.

Comment: @DarkNess go right on the line and go to inspect element and tell me what it says or make a photo

Comment: @DarkNess Make some public album,only you can see them

Comment: Now there is a public album.

Comment: @DarkNess I looked but I don't see a solution,if you say that the fiddle has the correct code, I use chrome and I don't see the lines,maybe is just a local problem

Comment: Opened in FireFox, there are also no lines, on my father's pc in desktop chrome also all is fine, only in mobile there are. I suppose you're right and it's a local problem. Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: If you want, post your last comment as an answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It did help! :)

Comment: @DarkNess No problem,was a simple answer but to find it was a long way :)